# Store a double within a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, double

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
fitnorm <- data.frame(dataset=0,mean=0,sd=0,normopl=0)
```

Which goes through the following iterative process

```
normdat <- rnorm(25, mean = 30, sd = sqrt(9))
fitnorm[i,1] <- normdat
fitnorm[i,2] <- mean(normdat)
fitnorm[i,3] <- sd(normdat)
fitnorm[i,4] <- qnorm(1-(400/1000), mean=fitnorm[i,2], sd=fitnorm[i,3])
```

However, I am getting this error.

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, 1, value = c(27.431413650154, 
30.3657212588031,  :  replacement has 25 rows, data has 1
```

I understand that this is becuase I am trying to place 'normdat' which is type double and size 25 into a single element of a dataframe. Shouldn't a dataframe be able to hold an object of type double? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't a dataframe be able to hold an object of type double? What am I doing wrong?

It can. But this is not what you're doing

In the line

```
## I've assumed i <- 1
fitnorm[i,1] <- normdat
```

you are trying to assign a numerical vector (`normdat`) to one cell of the data frame (i.e. row `i`, column 1)

Are you instead trying to do

```
fitnorm[i,1] <- normdat[i]
```

**Update**

As per your comment, you can't store a vector in a single item of a data.frame, you need to use a list:

```
lst <- list(dataset = normdat,
            mean = mean(normdat),
            sd = sd(normdat),
            normopl = qnorm(1-(400/1000), mean=fitnorm[i,2], sd=fitnorm[i,3]))

## Which gives
lst
$dataset
 [1] 33.43470 28.66693 29.41060 32.95761 32.66531 29.86056 31.61961 29.32424 28.07063 31.80155
[11] 32.88489 31.90562 31.81625 24.62625 31.19141 27.41913 31.43993 29.60108 29.73310 23.77482
[21] 28.50347 27.22960 24.65698 27.13001 35.85981

$mean
[1] 29.82336

$sd
[1] 2.981638

$normopl
[1] 30.57875
```

If you **did** want to use a `data.frame` you'd have to make every column the same length

```
fitnorm <- data.frame(dataset = normdat,
                  mean = mean(normdat),
                  sd = sd(normdat),
                  normopl = qnorm(1-(400/1000), mean=fitnorm[i,2], sd=fitnorm[i,3]))

head(fitnorm)
#   dataset     mean       sd  normopl
#1 33.43470 29.82336 2.981638 30.57875
#2 28.66693 29.82336 2.981638 30.57875
#3 29.41060 29.82336 2.981638 30.57875
#4 32.95761 29.82336 2.981638 30.57875
#5 32.66531 29.82336 2.981638 30.57875
#6 29.86056 29.82336 2.981638 30.57875
```

**Edit by OP**

The above code worked. However, since the list had to be iterative, I made a slight alteration.

```
fitnorm <- list(dataset=list(),mean=list(),sd=list(),normopl=list())

for (i in 1:5000){
    normdat <- rnorm(25, mean = 30, sd = sqrt(9))
    fitnorm$dataset[[i]] <- normdat
    fitnorm$mean[[i]]<- mean(normdat)
    fitnorm$sd[[i]] <- sd(normdat)
    fitnorm$normopl[[i]] <- qnorm(1-(400/1000), mean=fitnorm$mean[[i]], sd=fitnorm$sd[[i]])
    }

fitnorm$dataset[1]
[[1]]
 [1] 33.43470 28.66693 29.41060 32.95761 32.66531 29.86056 31.61961 29.32424 28.07063 31.80155
[11] 32.88489 31.90562 31.81625 24.62625 31.19141 27.41913 31.43993 29.60108 29.73310 23.77482
[21] 28.50347 27.22960 24.65698 27.13001 35.85981

fitnorm$mean[1]
[[1]]
[1] 29.82336

fitnorm$sd[1]
[[1]]
[1] 2.981638

fitnorm$normopl[1]
[[1]]
[1] 30.57875
```

**Update - Symbolix**

There's a 'rule of thumb' in `R` that I try to stick to that says to use an `lapply` instead of a `for` as it is **generally** more efficient (it works in `C`) - There's a lot of discussion about this on SO already.

Therefore, I would replace your `for` loop with

```
lst <- lapply(1:5000, function(x){

    normdat <- rnorm(25, mean = 30, sd = sqrt(9))

    list(fitnorm = list(dataset = normdat,
                        mean = mean(normdat),
                        sd = sd(normdat),
                        normopl = qnorm(1-(400/1000), mean = mean(normdat), sd = sd(normdat))
    ))
  })
```

And a quick bit of benchmarking:

```
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   fun_lapply() 220.2830 236.1661 252.7315 249.1904 267.1123 337.0799   100
 fun_for_loop() 373.5972 399.8972 427.1629 421.7407 442.4626 593.7227   100
```

Ultimately the gains in this example are marginal, but worth keeping in mind.

**Update - Symbolix 2**

You can also create a single `data.frame` if you prefer working with them:

Here I'm using the `data.table` package for the speed it offers

```
library(data.table)
lst <- lapply(1:5000, function(x){

  normdat <- rnorm(25, mean = 30, sd = sqrt(9))
  data.table(id = x,
             dataset = normdat,
             mean = mean(normdat),
             sd = sd(normdat),
             normopl = qnorm(1-(400/1000), mean=mean(normdat), sd=sd(normdat)))
})

##lst is now a list of data.tables, so we can 'rbind' them together
dt <- rbindlist(lst)

## now we have one data.table, and the 'id' column indicates 
## which dataset each row belongs too
dt
# id  dataset     mean       sd  normopl
# 1:    1 24.09486 29.46829 3.261638 30.29462
# 2:    1 26.30732 29.46829 3.261638 30.29462
# 3:    1 31.42603 29.46829 3.261638 30.29462
# 4:    1 29.69081 29.46829 3.261638 30.29462
# 5:    1 30.01235 29.46829 3.261638 30.29462
# ---                                         
# 124996: 5000 28.13584 30.39716 2.591752 31.05377
# 124997: 5000 27.44665 30.39716 2.591752 31.05377
# 124998: 5000 29.79728 30.39716 2.591752 31.05377
# 124999: 5000 28.73398 30.39716 2.591752 31.05377
# 125000: 5000 27.83779 30.39716 2.591752 31.05377
```

Comment: I am trying to hold all 25 values in a single element.

Comment: Then you need to use a list, not a data.frame

Comment: I was trying to avoid that :) Thank you.

Comment: given your required construct, I don't think you can. Lists are very useful to work with once you understand their power and move away from the 'typical' Excel / SQL single table thinking :)

Comment: @krthkskmr I understand your edit, but, I don't see why it **has** to be iterative? You can still create your desired structure without using a `for` loop.

Comment: It's because I am trying to create 5000 normal data sets, calculate a mean, sd and opl for all the 5000 data sets. I don't see any other way to do it. (I want to iterate over all 5000 data sets.)

Comment: @krthkskmr - I've updated my answer to show what I'm getting at. Ultimately an `lapply` is an 'iterative' process, but, I prefer it over `for` loops in `R`

Comment: This is perfect! I hate using for loops in R and that is why I insisted on using a data frame in the first place. Thanks again.

Comment: @krthkskmr - I've given you another update to show how you can store it in a single table (`data.frame` or `data.table`), if you prefer to work with the data this way

Comment: @Symbolox, No, I am going to take your suggestion and use lists, it is definitely a much more efficient way of doing it.